# VirtualBox Ubuntu 20.04 blinking cursor

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu

Kubuntu 18.04.4 Host. Ubuntu 20.04 guest settings as in the picture.  VirtualBox 6.1

This is the second time this has happened.  The install runs great for days or a week then dies with the black screen and blinking cursor. (Kubuntu 20.04 Guest with similar settings does not fail)

Do I have a setting(s) wrong?

[image]